# How is npx able to execute a module which I haven't installed?

Tags: node.js, npm

On my system, I have the default global packages -

```
$ npm -g ls
C:\Users\xxx\Documents\node-v18.12.1-win-x64
├── corepack@0.14.2
└── npm@9.6.0
```

and only `prettier` is installed locally -

```
$ npm ls
wl@1.0.0 C:\Users\xxx\dev\wl
└── prettier@3.0.3
```

attempting to run `nodemon` gives an expected error -

```
$ npx nodemon --version
Need to install the following packages:
  nodemon@3.0.1
Ok to proceed? (y) n
npm ERR! canceled

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-09-06T07_27_10_
091Z-debug-0.log
```

even though it's in my cache -

```
$ npm cache ls nodemon
make-fetch-happen:request-cache:https://registry.npmjs.org/nodemon
make-fetch-happen:request-cache:https://registry.npmjs.org/nodemon/-/nodemon-3.0
.1.tgz
```

Why does the execution of `eslint` not give the same error? What is the difference here between `nodemon` and `eslint`?

```
$ npx eslint --version
v8.31.0
```